# Why is my data-source not listed when creating an ad-hoc Variable?

Tags: prometheus, grafana

I have a working Grafana dashboard backed by a Prometheus data source, both products are up to date versions.

When I try to set up an ad-hoc variable, my data source is not listed and I can see no way to actually create the variable:

[image]

The [documentation](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/variables/variable-types/) is pretty minimal, can anyone explain what is going wrong?

Comment: Have you checked if everything is OK in: Configuration > Data Sources > Prometheus > Save & Test?

Comment: @MarceloÁviladeOliveira yes, double-checked but as I said I have a working dashboard; plenty of graphs on this data source.

Comment: Looks like a bug for me, you should open an incident for Grafana