# Can I apply a query/filter to all panel queries at dashboard level?

Tags: prometheus, grafana

I have a Prometheus server gathering metrics from several software installations. Each installation applies labels "Customer" & "System" to all metrics in the Prometheus relabel phase, and I have a Grafana dashboard which uses template variables `$Customer`, `$System` so my dashboard shows graphs for a single customer-system.

e.g. I can choose "Google/Test" or "Microsoft/Live" combinations.

This means *all* my queries are like `my_counter_total{Customer='$Customer', System='$System'}` which is rather tiring. Is there anyway to apply `{Customer='$Customer', System='$System'}` at dashboard level to all queries? The Grafana documentation hints it can be done but doesn't say how, and I cannot find a single example.

edit: As noted 'ad hoc queries' seem to be able to do this but the entire documentation is:

> Ad hoc filters are one of the most complex and flexible variable
> options available. Instead of a regular list of variable options, this
> variable allows you to build a dashboard-wide ad hoc query. Filters
> you apply in this manner are applied to all panels on the dashboard.

So they tell me it's very complicated and leave me hanging :)

Comment: Interesting question. How does grafana hint at that?

Comment: @aclowkay see Marcelo's answer. That's where I've come from but I can't see _how_

Answer (score 2):

You can do that using an "Ad hoc filter" variable.

1. Go to ***Dashboard settings*** > ***Variables*** > ***New***
2. Fill the options like the following example and click on ***Add***

[image]

3. In this example, an Ad hoc filter variable called "Disk" will show in your dashboard:

[image]

4. You can choose how many label/value pair expressions you want to be used in this filter. In the following example, it was chosen "mountpoint=/home/cds/tool/bitbucket" so, magically, only the disk with this mountpoint was showed:

[image]

Note: The "mountpoint=/home/cds/tool/bitbucket" will automatically be used for all query expressions of all panes in the dashboard.

See more details in Grafana documentation [here](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/variables/variable-types/add-ad-hoc-filters/).

Comment: Yes I've seen that documentation. It gives no explanation or example. If you know how to do it, can you expand your answer specific to my question?

Comment: You made another question related to this subject (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66778979/why-is-my-data-source-not-listed-when-creating-an-ad-hoc-variable), I think you first must resolve this issue so you're able to use the ad hoc variable in a dashboard.

Comment: Even when I fix that there is still zero documentation. If you know how to do this, perhaps you can show a screenshot what a valid adhoc variable looks like, because I cannot find this anywhere. If you don't know how to, a link to the docs isn't very helpful when they are so limited :)

Comment: I meant to say that, probably, you're not understanding how the Ad hoc variable works because, for some reason, it's not working as expected for you (based on the other related question you have made). Anyways... 1) I improved the answer by showing with details how the feature works, 2) It wasn't polite to downvote my answer since we are in the middle of the process of finding the solution to your problem.

Comment: That's just how SO works. Like questions, answers can be downvoted if they are not great then the vote changed later if they are improved (as has now hapepned). You shouldn't take it personally.

Comment: Sorry, in my understanding, this's not the way "vote down" works. Please, read the "What are the alternatives to downvoting?" item of the "vote down" page (https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down), special attention to "Downvoting is not meant as a substitute for communication and editing".

Comment: Thanks. Once the ad hoc filter is defined, I understand how it works. Basically, it's just a filter with a name; you define it, and then in the board, you select the tag you want to filter, and operator(`=`, `~=`, `!~`, etc.), and value. Like, tag "instance", operator "!~", value ".*test.*", so in all queries, instance containing "test" will be excluded.